# ASP.NET Core connect two table model returns NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a strange issue with model connection. I'm using ASP.NET Core with SQL Server and Entity Framework Core.

User model:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }    
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Order model:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
    //
}
```

I get an error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

when I'm trying to add orders to user with this code:

```
public void Test(User user)
{
    user.Orders.Add(new Order() { Test = "test" });
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The only solution was this but the problem is that the `ICollection<Order> Orders` count 0 every time:

```
private ICollection<Order> _orders;
public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders
{
    get { return _orders ?? (_orders = new Collection<Order>()); }
    set { _orders = value; }
}
```

I tried to make `ICollection<Order>` and `User` `virtual`, but the error stays the same.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove collection initialisation from class and add order in the following way:

```cs
public void Test(User user)
{
    _context.Orders.Add(new Order() { Test = "test", User = user });
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Works but I can't access to user.Orders only with _context.Orders.Where(o => o.User == user); Is there any reason for this? Why can't use user.Orders?

Comment: You have to Include them when loading user. `context.Users.Include(u => u.Orders).Where(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void Test(User user)
{
    _context.Orders.Add(new Order { Test = "test", UserId=user.Id});
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Works but I can't access to user.Orders only with _context.Orders.Where(o => o.UserId == user.Id); Is there any reason for this? Why can't use user.Orders?